# Order Random without duplicates on pages

Tags: wordpress

It's possible make loop with random without duplicate entries?

This is my code, but in page 2, repeat posts of page 1.

```
<?php global $query_string;

query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=rand' ); ?>

<?php while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

            <div class="post-content">
```

Comment: you could create an array of the id values that were retrieved during this query_posts and pass that array to the query_posts on the next page by appending 'post__not_in' => array(1,2,3) to your query_string: array(1,2,3) would be the array holding the id values from the previous page...or paginate the initial query results

Comment: uooh!! really thanks. Now i understand some more, but can you help me with a code example or similar? thanks

Comment: to seed the query and paginate the results per session, take a look at [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31647/is-it-possible-to-paginate-posts-correctly-that-are-random-ordered) ... they have the relevant code in that answer

Comment: that trick works! Only one thing... How close session? If i close browser and go to that page again, the results are the same.

Comment: you remove the cookie associated with the session session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();, you can read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31647/is-it-possible-to-paginate-posts-correctly-that-are-random-ordered

functions.php

```
session_start();

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_posts_orderby');

function edit_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {

    $seed = $_SESSION['seed'];
    if (empty($seed)) {
      $seed = rand();
      $_SESSION['seed'] = $seed;
    }

    $orderby_statement = 'RAND('.$seed.')';
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

Comment: I have implemented this, however is it possible to have it so that it changes on refresh? As this only changes when I clear my cookies and cache.