# WooCommerce random products without duplicates

Tags: php, wordpress, random, woocommerce, product

I wonder if there is a way to show random products, distributed over several pages, without having any duplicates?

Right know I have the following code in functions.php:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );

function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
$sortby['rand'] = 'Random';
return $sortby;
}
```

The pages are triggered by ajax (infinite scroll). Every time 20 products are loaded (representing the pages).

Is there a way to prevent duplicates from being shown?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Thinking further and with the help of **PHP native functions on arrays**, I think that I have some solution using these functions **on your existing code**:

- `array_rand($my_array);`
- `array_unique($my_array);`

So

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args' );
function custom_woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args( $args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    if ( 'random_list' == $orderby_value ) {
        $args['orderby'] = 'rand';
        $args['order'] = '';
        $args['meta_key'] = '';
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['random_list'] = 'Random';
    return $sortby;
}
```

---

Yes it is possible with that solution [based on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092249/order-random-without-duplicates-on-pages/19102599#19102599). This is the code:

```
session_start();

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby' );

function custom_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $sortby ) {

    $seed = $_SESSION['seed'];
    if (empty($seed)) {
      $seed = rand();
      $_SESSION['seed'] = $seed;
    }

    $sortby = 'RAND('.$seed.')';
    return $sortby;
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme

---

Reference: [Order Random without duplicates on pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092249/order-random-without-duplicates-on-pages/19102599#19102599)

Comment: What about telling `pre_get_posts` to order by `rand`?

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising. But will the randomization still work, when I reload the page?

Comment: What i meant was, how to “reset“ the session on reload, so that the random order will change

Comment: actually the updated answer is not working with pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the main products that appear when you go the main shop page or do you mean in a widget?

Comment: Main shop, no widget.